# Connect 2 separate laptops using docker swarm?

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, docker-swarm

I want to build a small blockchain network between 2 laptops (as an initial step). I am using Hyperledger Fabric and Hyperledger Composer on each laptop.

1. Can I use docker swarm to connect these 2 laptops then use Hyperledger Fabric and Hyperledger Composer to my blockchain network?
2. If the answer of question 1 is yes, can I do these without any cloud account (like amz, etc.) and without paying money?
3. If the answer of questions 1 and 2 is no, how can do my target?

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes you can use docker swarm to connect 2 laptops and use hyperledger frameworks on them.  [Setup hyperledger fabric on multiple hosts using docker swarm](https://medium.com/@wahabjawed/hyperledger-fabric-on-multiple-hosts-a33b08ef24f)
2. Since you are doing this on your laptop locally, you don't need to pay anything to anyone.